# Hide HTML elements based on input="radio" w CSS only

Tags: html, css, radio-button, hide, display

I have labels and select lists associated with 2 different classes. Based on the radio button checked I would like to hide the elements associated to one class and show the elements associated to the other class.

HTML
Radio Button

```
<p>Your Preferred Input</p>
            <label for="qual_quant">Qualitatively</label>
            <input type=radio id="rb_qual" name="qual_quant" value="qual">
            <label for="qual_quant">Quantitatively</label>
            <input type=radio id="rb_quant" name="qual_quant" value="quant" checked>
```

This is an example of the code to be shown when #rb_qual = "qual"

```
<label for="fs_qual_tech" class="fs_qual">Technical - Qual</label>
                        <select id="fs_qual_tech" name="fs_qual_tech" class="fs_qual">
                            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Trait...</option>
                            <option value="2.5">Very Poor</option>
                            <option value="8">Poor</option>
                            <option value="13">Good</option>
                            <option value="18">Very Good</option>
                        </select>
```

Below is an example of code to be hidden when #rb_qual="qual"

```
<div class="fs_quant_div">
          <label for="fs_quant_tech" class="fs_quant">Technical - Quant</label>
                    
          <select id="fs_quant_tech" name="fs_quant_tech" class="fs_quant">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Assign Points...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

CSS
condition which hides all .fs_qual elements

```
.fs_qual {
    display: none;
}
```

Trigger which shows .fs_qual

```
#rb_qual:checked ~ .fs_qual {
    display: block;
}
```

Everything works -- except that trigger. If someone can help with this trigger I can expand on it for the other class and radio button value.

[Screenshot of how it looks / functions(not)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cipjL.png)

Comment: For this to work as you want (using only css), the content element for each radio must come immediately after the respective radio. Otherwise, you will only be able to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the trigger work for both cases.
You have added the quants inside the div.
So, the selector `#rb_quant:checked ~ .fs_quant`  would not work as expected.
Please check this fiddle and let me know.
https://jsfiddle.net/xqekr762/